# IE doesn't allow parameters in local html URLs?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, parameter-passing

Does anyone know why all these URLs work in FireFox... but the last 2 don't
work in IE?

```
file:///C:\file.html
C:\file.html
file:///C:\file.html?a=1
C:\file.html?a=1
```

IE seems gives "can't find" as if it's trying to include "?a=1" as part
of the filename itself.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this mere academic curiosity, or are you trying to solve a problem with this? If the latter is the case, what value does the query string provide when accessing local files via these means?